# How to put result into DIV from JSON?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jquery-ui

From the below function I am getting results. Now I want to put that result into a div. So how should I put the result into a div?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "../ajaxaction.php",
        data: {
            action: 'alllist'
        },
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (msg) {
            for (var i = 0; i < msg.length; i++) {
                var uname = msg[i].user_name;
                var vtitle = msg[i].video_title;
                var vid = msg[i].video_id;
                var vthumb = msg[i].video_thumb;
            }
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: What have you tried here? I can see your Vars, but can you add your HTML as well, because I dont see a DIV anywhere ?

Comment: as i can see from your code you looping throught list an put values of each record into some local values, each time overriding them...

Comment: if you need to display all the list on page inside some dive i suggest to use something like this:$('body').append('<div/>')

Answer (score 2):

You can append the result in to div with the format you like but a simple way of adding would be. You can use [append()](http://api.jquery.com/append/) function to keep the added html with new html for each iteration of loop.

```
  success: function(msg){ 
       for (var i = 0; i < msg.length; i++) { 
        var uname = msg[i].user_name;
        var vtitle = msg[i].video_title;
        var vid = msg[i].video_id; 
        var vthumb = msg[i].video_thumb;
         $('#divId').append("Name: " + uname + "," + "Title: " + vtitle +
                            "Id: " + vid + "," + "Thumb: " + vthumb + "<br />");
       }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "../ajaxaction.php",
       data: { action:'alllist'},
       dataType: 'json',
       success: function(msg){ 
       for (var i = 0; i < msg.length; i++) { 
        var uname = msg[i].user_name;
        var vtitle = msg[i].video_title;
        var vid = msg[i].video_id; 
        var vthumb = msg[i].video_thumb;

        $("#container").html("Username: " + uname + "<br />Video Title: " + vtitle + "<br />Vide ID: " + vid + "<br />Video Thumb: " + vthumb);
       }


   }});

});
```

Answer (score 1):

If your div exists:

```
jQuery('div selector').append(uname+' '+vtitle+...whatever variable and format);
```

If not

`jQuery('element selector to put the div in').append('<div id="aID" class="some classes">'+uname+' '+vtitle+...whatever variable and format...+'</div>');`

Answer (score 0):

you can do this:

```
success: function(msg){ 
   $.each(msg, function(i, item){
      $('#divid').html('User Name : '+item.user_name+ 
                       'Video title : '+item.video_title+
                       'Video Id : 'item.video_id+
                       'Video Thumb : 'item.video_thumb );
      });
}
```