# Reading json result into divs

Tags: jquery

I am trying to place the content of the first two objects "sunrise" and "sunset" into two divs.

json;

```
results: {sunrise: "8:04:59 AM", sunset: "3:55:14 PM", solar_noon: "12:00:07 PM", day_length: "07:50:15", civil_twilight_begin: "7:24:53 AM", …}
```

My code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.ajax({ 
    type: 'GET', 
    url: 'https://api.sunrise-sunset.org/json?lat=51.4700223&lng=-0.4542955&date=today', 
    data: { get_param: 'value' }, 
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (data) { 
        $('#set').html(data[0].sunrise);
        $('#rise').html(data[0].sunset);
    }
  });
});
```

Many thanks in advance for your time

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14376156/how-to-put-result-into-div-from-json

Comment: You forgot the part where you describe the problem.  What isn't working?  When you debug, do your variables contain what you expect them to?  If `results` is the object you're showing before the code, why are you treating it like an array?

Comment: data is an object and results (also an object) is a property of data.
sunset and sunrise are both properties of the results object.
So use `data.results.sunrise` and `data.results.sunset`

Comment: @ AlbertVanHalen hi and thanks for your reply. I changed my code, see above and I now have the result I needed,

Comment: @DCJones: please submit your edit an an answer and mark it as accepted.  Editing the question just leaves it as a question with no answer.